# Log4j2 SmtpAppender sends ERRORS but not Exceptions

Tags: logging, log4j2

I encountered some weird problem with log4j2. Whenever I log events with the *error* level an email is sent which is what is expected. However whenever an exception is being thrown, it is not sent via SMTP appender (I tested other appenders, Console and RollingFile - both appenders work). Here is my log4j2.xml configuration:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
      <Appenders>
        <SMTP 
         name="Mailer" 
         subject="ERROR LOG" 
         to="to@example.com" 
         from="from@example.com"
         smtpUsername="from@example.com" 
         smtpPassword="example_password" 
           smtpHost="example.host">
           
           <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
           
           <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
           </Filters>
           
        </SMTP>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="info"/>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="info"/>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info"/>
        <Root level="warn">
          <AppenderRef ref="Mailer"/>
        </Root>
      </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Have I missed something ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "whenever an exception is being thrown, it is not sent via SMTP appender"?  Are you logging the exception as an error?

Comment: No, I just want to be notified that an exception has been thrown. I'm sure it is possible to configure log4j2 for that purpose. If e.g. SQLException has been thrown, I want to get an email with it.

Comment: Log4j has no magic way to hook into when an exception is being thrown. You have to use something like logger.caught() or logger.error() in your catch block to log the exception. Once you do that you can have the log event cause the appender to send the email.